# How can I set UICollectionviewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I've added an image in collection view cell in Storyboard. I want to set the image rounded. However, it is not work.

**ViewController**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}
```

**ContentCollectionViewCell**

```
class ContentCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var userProfileImageView: UIImageView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // called
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // never called
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setRoundedImage()
    }

    func setRoundedImage() {
        userProfileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userProfileImageView.frame.width * 0.5
    }

}
```

But it work this way in **ViewController**.

Why `init(frame: CGRect)`in **ContentCollectionViewCell** is never called? and what is the best practice if I want to set pre-defined content in UICollectionCell class?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCollectionViewCell
    cell.userProfileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userProfileImageView.frame.width * 0.5
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cell class you can do any initial settings of cell:

```
class FV_Cell: UICollectionViewCell
 {
     override func awakeFromNib()
     {
         super.awakeFromNib()
           // Initialization code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works when put everything in awakeFromNib

Answer (score 4):

Try this code my be help full.

That round the cell. //Rounding full cell

```
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor;
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
```

OR

Add following in Cell Class // Round imageview of cell

```
class ExploreCategoryCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{

@IBOutlet var coverImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var lblCoverName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblArtistName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblTags: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblE: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.coverImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    self.coverImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it for all cells. Write this code to your `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.userProfileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userProfileImageView.frame.width * 0.5
cell.userProfileImageView!.clipsToBounds = true
```

Hope it will work...!!

Answer (score 0):

You should add rounding line of code in

```
layoutSubviews()
```

not in init()